# Can I remove documents of mongodb using regex expression?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have not find a method to do it yet.
If we can not remove documents using regex expression, what can we do to make it done? And why does not mongodb provide such a driver ?

Answer (score 15):

The [`.remove()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) method just takes a query object, so regular expressions are just a standard query for MongoDB:

```js
db.collection.remove({ "field": /^string/ })
```

Removes anything that has "field" that starts with "string"

Look at the documentation for [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) as well.

Comment: Thank~  I just wonder why it does not support such a operation.

Comment: @Canoe What do you mean "does not support"? Any "query" is allowed, this and the full BSON form of `$regex` are valid queries.

Comment: to remove documents using regex expression

Comment: @Canoe That is what the statement above does. It removes matching a regular expression. If that is not clear then your question is not clear. Either try it or explain what you mean by editing your question

Comment: Now I know it can remove documents using regex expression. Perhaps 'I just wonder why it does not support such a operation' makes unclear statements because of my poor English.

Comment: @Canoe Language does appear to be the problem here. The statement works. If you expect something different then you need to find out how to explain yourself, change your question and then notify when you have made yourself clearer. You are currently not explaining what else you could possibly mean.

Answer (score 1):

Documents can be remove using `remove()` method and `$regex` query.

For example

```
db.users.remove({"email" :  { $regex : /$test/}})
```

It will remove all user email starts with 'test'.

```
db.users.remove({"email" :  { $regex : /@yopmail.com$/}})
```

It will remove all user email ends with 'yopmail.com'

Details are explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), mongoDB official site

Answer (score 1):

I have used [deleteMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/) method:

```
db.collection.deleteMany({ "field": /^string/ })
```